# Cassandra schema from 0.7 to 1.0

Tags: migration, cassandra, data-migration

I have a 0.7 cassandra working cluster. I've created a new empty cluster with cassandra 1.0 and I'd like to "import" the schema of a keyspace in the 0.7 cluster (made of more than 40 CFs) -- I'd like to avoid many Create Column Family ... is there a way to do it?

show schema from cli only works from 0.8 afaik -- I've tried to copy data files (sstables) from a 0.7 node to a 1.0 node just to use the "show schema" but I have no idea how to tell cassandra that the data should be loaded at the startup (I've placed sstables in a folder located under the data folder specified in the Yaml)

Regards,
Carlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the Schema and Migrations data files from the system keyspace data of one of your 0.7 nodes to one of your 1.0 nodes (while it's shut down, and removing its own Schema + Migrations files first).  Then restart it.

Comment: I was missing that schema is located in system keyspace. thanks.